# Genexus FromJson no funciona en la evo2

Tags: genexus

Estoy tratando de guardar una respuesta de tipo json en un sdt (no contiene colecciones).

Es un problema que siempre he tenido en el cual FromJson nunca asigna nada al sdt. El json es valido y lastimosamente no puedo cambiar la respuesta a xml porque no tengo acceso a la app que lo genera.

FromXml funciona perfectamente en la evo2 y FromJson solo funciona en GX15, pero ocupo hacer esto en la evo2.

Apreciaria su ayuda/orientación.

Comment: Este es un sitio de preguntas/respuestas, no un foro de discusión. Una pregunta concreta es "¿Cómo asigno a sdt con FromJson?", y adjuntas el código con el cual estas ejercitando esa capacidad. Mira [mre]

Comment: Pues deberían agregar una validación para solo aceptar preguntas y no estarle repitiendo eso a los nuevos.

Answer (score 0):

Como estas?

El json lo recibes mediante un servicio imagino, por lo cual, podrias usar esta herramienta para que te arme correctamente el SDT con los datos necesarios:

[Link a wiki GeneXus](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?22574,Json%202%20SDT)

Seguramente tu problema viene por le lado de que no es compatible el sdt con el json que le estas queriendo asignar. Podrias probar con eso que te va a generar las estructuras ok. Suerte!